# Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value of property

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-of-dict

Let's say I have an array of four objects:

```
var jsObjects = [
   {a: 1, b: 2}, 
   {a: 3, b: 4}, 
   {a: 5, b: 6}, 
   {a: 7, b: 8}
];
```

Is there a way that I can get the third object (`{a: 5, b: 6}`) by the value of the property `b` for example without a `for...in` loop?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, as long as the value of b is unique among all of the objects in your array (which it is in this example)

Comment: @undefined Pretty sure op wants to search the array for at the object having `b = 6`

Comment: Related: [Find an object by property value in an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7364150/3853934)

Comment: I like short & sweet and compatible with pre-ES6 browsers...
jsObjects.find(function(x) {if(x.b == 6) return x})

You can use it to grab the property a at the same time...

jsObjects.find(function(x) {if(x.b == 6) return x}).a

Answer (score 1819):

`Filter` array of objects, which property matches value, returns array:

```
var result = jsObjects.filter(obj => {
  return obj.b === 6
})
```

See the [MDN Docs on Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const jsObjects = [
  {a: 1, b: 2}, 
  {a: 3, b: 4}, 
  {a: 5, b: 6}, 
  {a: 7, b: 8}
]

let result = jsObjects.filter(obj => {
  return obj.b === 6
})

console.log(result)
```

`Find` the value of the first element/object in the array, otherwise `undefined` is returned.

```
var result = jsObjects.find(obj => {
  return obj.b === 6
})
```

See the [MDN Docs on Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const jsObjects = [
  {a: 1, b: 2}, 
  {a: 3, b: 4}, 
  {a: 5, b: 6}, 
  {a: 7, b: 8}
]

let result = jsObjects.find(obj => {
  return obj.b === 6
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This will return an array

Comment: @nickf. I think it should, what if there are more objects with same properties? Otherwise: `result[0]` will be the first (unique) object in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it depends on what's needed. If it is just one item, I think `filter` isn't a great option, since it will firstly create a new unneeded object, and secondly it will continue through the entire array even when the object is found.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `filter` is only supported in modern browsers (i.e. IE9 and above) as it's part of ES5. So if you want to support older browsers you might want to fall back on one of the other methods suggested.

Comment: To have it return just the first is easy. Add "[0]" to the end. #javaScriptIsAwesome! var result = jsObjects.filter(function( obj ) {
  return obj.b == 6;
})[0];

Comment: The question is "get JavaScript *object*", not "array of objects".

Comment: @Gothdo is right. To get object we can use Array.find: 
var result = jsObjects.find(function( obj ) {
  return obj.b === 6;
});

Comment: if I change something in a result object, will it be also changed in the jsObjects array?

Comment: Using the exact number 6 isn't useful for me. How do you pass in a variable?

Comment: @user3925803 - if you have `var x = 6;` above `var result`, just replace the hard-coded `6` in the function with your variable (`x`).

Comment: also there is a tiny utility for this called [super-array](https://www.npmjs.com/package/super-array)

Comment: We should actually be using find: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

It functions the same as filter but returns the first matching object, not an array.

Comment: @VoA `find()` is an option, but it's not a "should" thing as every development house is different and not all are standardized on ES6 (especially in big companies where change is slow). If someone wants to return the first found object using `filter()`, then they just have to tack `[0]` to the end.

Comment: @thdoan Yeah sure I hear you.

Comment: @elclanrs is the element of result shallow copy of elements of jsObjects or deep copy?

Comment: How could find the value in both a and b values?

Comment: Also... when using a var... use == instead of ===

Comment: this answer broke my form. return val should be json; filter returns an array

Comment: @J.E.C. - technically, *you* broke your form when you thought this answer was what you needed.  The answer is solid for at least 1500 other people.

Answer (score 486):

```
jsObjects.find(x => x.b === 6)
```

From MDN:

> The [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method returns a value in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise `undefined` is returned.

---

Side note: methods like `find()` and arrow functions are not supported by older browsers (like IE), so if you want to support these browsers, you should transpile your code using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: Note that this is not supported in IE

Comment: @29er Yes, I wrote that "methods like `find()` and arrow functions are not supported by all browsers".

Comment: This is the best option if you want to modify the object in the original array. `filter()` returns a copy of the object, _not_ the original object, so changes will not be reflected in the original array

Comment: This is not exactly equivalent to @elclanrs's answer using `filter()`: it returns only the first match.

Comment: @thdoan The OP asked for "the object", not "an array of matching objects". elclanrs's answer is wrong.

Comment: This example uses ECMAScript 6 arrow function. In case of errors when using arrow functions, there are other ways out. See
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
and (https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/)

Comment: Upvoted because it's not supported by IE.  It's time to move on and I'm using it for that very reason.

Answer (score 199):

I don't know why you are against a for loop (presumably you meant a `for loop`, not specifically `for..in`), they are fast and easy to read. Anyhow, here's some options.

***For loop:***

```
function getByValue(arr, value) {

  for (var i=0, iLen=arr.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if (arr[i].b == value) return arr[i];
  }
}
```

***.filter***

```
function getByValue2(arr, value) {

  var result  = arr.filter(function(o){return o.b == value;} );

  return result? result[0] : null; // or undefined

}
```

***.forEach***

```
function getByValue3(arr, value) {

  var result = [];

  arr.forEach(function(o){if (o.b == value) result.push(o);} );

  return result? result[0] : null; // or undefined

}
```

If, on the other hand you really did mean for..in and want to find an object with any property with a value of 6, then you must use for..in unless you pass the names to check.

**Example**

```
function getByValue4(arr, value) {
  var o;

  for (var i=0, iLen=arr.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    o = arr[i];

    for (var p in o) {
      if (o.hasOwnProperty(p) && o[p] == value) {
        return o;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: which one is the fastest one?

Comment: Foor loop by far the fastest method (https://jsperf.com/extract-props/1).

Comment: with es6 and later use: 
for(let value of arr)

Comment: @RobG any specific reason to store `arr.length` in `iLen` instead of directly using `arr.length` in the for condition as `i<arr.length`?

Comment: @VikasPrasad—just a minor performance enhancement, probably doesn't help now but in the early days it did.

Comment: Brillent Sollution

Comment: I often think `filter()` is the _safer_ method because it assumes more than one result.

Answer (score 80):

**Ways to achieve the requirement :**

1. Using [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method **:**

```js
const jsObject = [
   {a: 1, b: 2}, 
   {a: 3, b: 4}, 
   {a: 5, b: 6}, 
   {a: 7, b: 8}
];

const filteredResult = jsObject.find((e) => e.b == 6);

console.log(filteredResult);
```

2. Using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method **:**

```js
const jsObjects = [
   {a: 1, b: 2}, 
   {a: 3, b: 4}, 
   {a: 5, b: 6}, 
   {a: 7, b: 8}
];

const filterObj = jsObjects.filter((e) => e.b == 6);

console.log(filterObj[0]);
```

3. Using [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop **:**

```js
const jsObjects = [
   {a: 1, b: 2}, 
   {a: 3, b: 4}, 
   {a: 5, b: 6}, 
   {a: 7, b: 8}
];

for (const i in jsObjects) {
  if (jsObjects[i].b == 6) {
    console.log(jsObjects[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

**OK,** there are few ways to do that, but let's start with the simplest one and latest approach to do this, this function is called `find()`.

Just be careful when you using `find` to as even IE11 dosn't support it, so it needs to be transpiled...

so you have this object as you said:

```
var jsObjects = [
   {a: 1, b: 2}, 
   {a: 3, b: 4}, 
   {a: 5, b: 6}, 
   {a: 7, b: 8}
];
```

and you can write a function and get it like this:

```
function filterValue(obj, key, value) {
  return obj.find(function(v){ return v[key] === value});
}
```

and use the function like this:

```
filterValue(jsObjects, "b", 6); //{a: 5, b: 6}
```

Also in **ES6** for even shortened version:

```
const filterValue = (obj, key, value)=> obj.find(v => v[key] === value);
```

This method only return the first value which match..., for better result and browser support, you can use `filter`:

```
const filterValue = (obj, key, value)=> obj.filter(v => v[key] === value);
```

and we will return `[{a: 5, b: 6}]`...

This method will return an array instead...

You simpley use for loop as well, create a function like this:

```
function filteredArray(arr, key, value) {
  const newArray = [];
  for(i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++) {
    if(arr[i][key] === value) {
      newArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
 return newArray;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
filteredArray(jsObjects, "b", 6); //[{a: 5, b: 6}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Alireza.
Very complete answer.

As for the .filter part:
< This method will return an array instead...
Not the most elegant solution, but consider adding [0] at the end, for a quick fix.
    const filterValue = (obj, key, value)=> obj.filter(v => v[key] === value)[0];

Answer (score 31):

See this documentation [***`Array.prototype.find()`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

***Example:***

```
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findCherries(fruit) { 
    return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(findCherries)); 
// { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```

Comment: Not clear how this works with the 'find()' method you're calling. Additionally Object.values() is not supported in Internet Explorer.

Comment: It seems that the link is mistaken. The author probably intended this one: [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: What does this return if it doesn't find anything? ```undefined?```

Comment: @OliverDixon yes.

Answer (score 23):

Using underscore.js:

```
var foundObject = _.findWhere(jsObjects, {b: 6});
```

Comment: Deprecated. Use `_.find` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40958199/12695188

Answer (score 21):

It looks like in the ECMAScript 6 proposal there are the `Array` methods `find()` and `findIndex()`. MDN also offers polyfills which you can include to get the functionality of these across all browsers.

[`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
function isPrime(element, index, array) {
    var start = 2;
    while (start <= Math.sqrt(element)) {
        if (element % start++ < 1) return false;
    }
    return (element > 1);
}

console.log( [4, 6, 8, 12].find(isPrime) ); // undefined, not found
console.log( [4, 5, 8, 12].find(isPrime) ); // 5
```

[`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
function isPrime(element, index, array) {
    var start = 2;
    while (start <= Math.sqrt(element)) {
        if (element % start++ < 1) return false;
    }
    return (element > 1);
}

console.log( [4, 6, 8, 12].findIndex(isPrime) ); // -1, not found
console.log( [4, 6, 7, 12].findIndex(isPrime) ); // 2
```

Answer (score 19):

If you are looking for a single result, rather than an array, may I suggest reduce?

Here is a solution in plain 'ole javascript that returns a matching object if one exists, or null if not.

```
var result = arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) { return (curr.b === 6) ? curr : prev; }, null);
```

Answer (score 18):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the object in the array whose `b` property is `6`?

```
var found;
jsObjects.some(function (obj) {
  if (obj.b === 6) {
    found = obj;
    return true;
  }
});
```

Or if you were using underscore:

```
var found = _.select(jsObjects, function (obj) {
  return obj.b === 6;
});
```

Comment: [`some`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.17) just returns true or false, it doesn't return the matching object.

Comment: @RobG yep, well aware. Note how I'm not assigning the value from it? :) It's just being used here as a way to short-circuit the loop.

Comment: Overcomplicated. `.some()` is meant to determine whether some element in the array passes the test. In this case it would be better to use `.forEach()`, since you already decided to assign the result to a variable.

Comment: @Gothdo why would you continue looping through the array when you already have the result? The `return true` in a `.some` is essentially like a `break` in a for loop.

Answer (score 14):

You can use it with the arrow function as well like as below :

```
var demoArray = [
   {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
   {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
   {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

var result = demoArray.filter( obj => obj.name === 'apples')[0];
console.log(result);
// {name: 'apples', quantity: 2}
```

Answer (score 11):

How about using `_.find(collection, [predicate=_.identity], [fromIndex=0])` of [lo-dash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2) to get object from array of objects by object property value. You could do something like this:

```
var o = _.find(jsObjects, {'b': 6});
```

Arguments:

```
collection (Array|Object): The collection to inspect.
[predicate=_.identity] (Function): The function invoked per iteration.
[fromIndex=0] (number): The index to search from.
```

Returns

```
(*): Returns the matched element (in your case, {a: 5, b: 6}), else undefined.
```

In terms of performance, `_.find()` is faster as it only pulls the first object with property `{'b': 6}`, on the other hand, if suppose your array contains multiple objects with matching set of properties (key:value), then you should consider using `_.filter()` method. So in your case, as your array has a single object with this property, I would use `_.find()`.

Answer (score 8):

Made the best/fastest part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13964619/3093731) more re-usable & clear:

```
function getElByPropVal(myArray, prop, val){
    for (var i = 0, length = myArray.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i][prop] == val){
            return myArray[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var result = jsObjects.filter(x=> x.b === 6);
```

will be better, using return in filter sometimes you can't get result (I dunno why)

Answer (score 3):

To get first object from array of objects by a specific property value:

```js
function getObjectFromObjectsArrayByPropertyValue(objectsArray, propertyName, propertyValue) {
  return objectsArray.find(function (objectsArrayElement) {
    return objectsArrayElement[propertyName] == propertyValue;
  });
}

function findObject () {
  var arrayOfObjectsString = document.getElementById("arrayOfObjects").value,
      arrayOfObjects,
      propertyName = document.getElementById("propertyName").value,
      propertyValue = document.getElementById("propertyValue").value,
      preview = document.getElementById("preview"),
      searchingObject;
  
  arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(arrayOfObjectsString);
  
  console.debug(arrayOfObjects);
  
  if(arrayOfObjects && propertyName && propertyValue) {
    searchingObject = getObjectFromObjectsArrayByPropertyValue(arrayOfObjects, propertyName, propertyValue);
    if(searchingObject) {
      preview.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(searchingObject, false, 2);
    } else {
      preview.innerHTML = "there is no object with property " + propertyName + " = " + propertyValue + " in your array of objects";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
pre {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #f3f2f2;
}

textarea, button {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Input Data:</legend>
  <label>Put here your array of objects</label>
  <textarea rows="7" id="arrayOfObjects">
  [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2},
    {"a": 3, "b": 4},
    {"a": 5, "b": 6},
    {"a": 7, "b": 8, "c": 157}
  ]
  </textarea>

  <hr>

  <label>property name: </label> <input type="text" id="propertyName"  value="b"/>
  <label>property value: </label> <input type="text" id="propertyValue" value=6 />
     
</fieldset>
<hr>
<button onclick="findObject()">find object in array!</button>
<hr>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Searching Result:</legend>
  <pre id="preview">click find</pre>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using find with bind to pass specific key values to a callback function.

```
   function byValue(o) { 
       return o.a === this.a && o.b === this.b; 
   };   

   var result = jsObjects.find(byValue.bind({ a: 5, b: 6 }));
```

Answer (score -31):

```
var jsObjects = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6}, {a: 7, b: 8}];
```

to access the third object, use: `jsObjects[2];`
to access the third object b value, use: `jsObjects[2].b;`