# How can I read keys and values from nestable list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I use in my project nestable list extenstion. How can I read, using jquery, keys and values from this list?

List's code looks like this:

```
<div class="dd" id="list1">
    <ol class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">Item 1</li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">Item 2</li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">Item 3</li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">Item 4</li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="5">Item 5</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Serialized output looks like this:

> [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5}]

And output is generated by this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.dd').nestable();
    //Watch for list changes and show serialized output
    function update_out(selector, sel2){
        var out = $(selector).nestable('serialize');
        $(sel2).html(window.JSON.stringify(out));
    }

    update_out('#list1',"#out1");

    $('#list1').on('change', function() {
        update_out('#list1',"#out1");
    });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property):

```
var test = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5}]    
var result = test.filter(function( obj) {
  return obj.id == 1;
});
```