# From a Single JavaScriptObject to Multiple JavaScriptObjects

Tags: javascript

I have the following javaScript object

```
var stats = [
    {x: 10,  y: 300, clr:'blue'},
    {x: 16,  y: 600, clr:'blue'},
    {x: 26,  y: 300, clr:'yellow'},
    {x: 36,  y: 200, clr:'yellow'},
    {x: 46,  y: 700, clr:'green'},
    {x: 56,  y: 100, clr:'green'},
];
```

How could I able to get the following objects? Each object seperated based on `clr` property The main key points are to separate and append the last object of the previous object to the first object for new object.This step is required to connect lines between.

```
 var stats1 = [
    {x:10,  y:300, clr:'blue'},
    {x:16,  y:600, clr:'blue'},
 ];

 var stats2 = [
    {x:16,  y:600, clr:'yellow'},
    {x:26,  y:300, clr:'yellow'},
    {x:36,  y:200, clr:'yellow'}
 ];

 var stats3 = [
    {x:36,  y:200, clr:'green'},
    {x:46,  y:700, clr:'green'},
    {x:56,  y:100, clr:'green'}
];
```

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: Clearly it should be "JavaScript objects", not "Java objects".

Comment: "Comparing Java to JavaScript is like comparing a car to a carpet. They have nothing in common other than sounding similar."

Comment: How can they both be OK? They're completely different languages!

Comment: Javascript and Java are completely different language.What you are talking about is Javascript Object aren't you?

Comment: Sorry I have fixed. It is javascript object

Comment: @elclanrs, I have been working on this project http://jsfiddle.net/53ygp9ut/2/ . Initially I have started with one javascript objects and Kendo-UI does not allow me to customize color property and I ended up to divide the javascript object based on their colors by doing so it works and requires this step which I am stuck. Again, key point here is to append previous last javascript object as a first javascript for new javascript

Comment: I don't understand the pattern. I thought you were separating them by color, but why is there a yellow in `stats3`?

Comment: Sorry, My bad. I have corrected. Thanks for catching it up.

Comment: I fail to see how the extra yellow and green are created.

Comment: @jakekimds, if I do not add the last object from previous then I could not able to connect them.Imagine that each object is a line and in order to connect them your objects needs to have at least one common. I hope I am clearer.

Comment: Although it does not completely answer your question, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13964186/3161440) might help.

Comment: Yes it is partial answer. it does seperation. But I am missing the last object to append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution as you want last object to be 1st of the next array object:

```js
var stats = [
{x: 10,  y: 300, clr:'blue'},
{x: 16,  y: 600, clr:'blue'},
{x: 26,  y: 300, clr:'yellow'},
{x: 36,  y: 200, clr:'yellow'},
{x: 46,  y: 700, clr:'green'},
{x: 56,  y: 100, clr:'green'},
];

function groupBy( array ,prop, f )
{
  var groups = {};
  
  ///grouping & sorting
  array.forEach( function( o )
  {
    var group = JSON.stringify( f(o) );
    groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
    groups[group].push( o );  
  });
  
  var last_prop = "" ; 
  var last_elm = {} ; 
 
  for(var key in groups )
  {
    if(last_prop !== "")
    {
      
      last_elm[prop] = groups[key][0][prop] ; 
      groups[key].unshift(last_elm);
    }
    
    last_prop = key;
    last_elm = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(groups[key][groups[key].length - 1])));
  }
  
  return Object.keys(groups).map( function( group )
  {
    return groups[group]; 
  });
}

var result = groupBy(stats, "clr", function(item)
{
  return [item.clr];
});

console.log(result);
    document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

if it doesn't work try jsbin version http://jsbin.com/tudahibefo/1/

Comment: I could not able to test your question without adding `stats`. Could you please add input

Comment: Thanks  a lot kwan, it is generic and modular code.

Comment: I modified it to make it more generic by moving clr as function parameter

Comment: any idea of the following question which is related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203009/sort-javascript-and-then-append-object

Answer (score 1):

```js
var stats = [
    {x: 10,  y: 300, clr:'blue'},
    {x: 16,  y: 600, clr:'blue'},
    {x: 26,  y: 300, clr:'yellow'},
    {x: 36,  y: 200, clr:'yellow'},
    {x: 46,  y: 700, clr:'green'},
    {x: 56,  y: 100, clr:'green'},
];
var stats1 = []; // blue
var stats2 = []; // yellow
var stats3 = []; // green
var last_item = null;

for (var i = 0; i < stats.length; i++) {
  var cur_item = stats[i];
  switch (cur_item.clr) {
    case "blue":
      target = stats1;
      break;
    case "yellow":
      target = stats2;
      break;
    case "green":
      target = stats3;
      break;
  }
  if (last_item && last_item.clr != cur_item.clr) {
    // Push last item of previous colow onto new color
    target.push({
      x: last_item.x,
      y: last_item.y,
      clr: cur_item.clr
    });
  }
  target.push(cur_item);
  last_item = cur_item;

}
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(stats1) + "<br>" + JSON.stringify(stats2) + "<br>" + JSON.stringify(stats3);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar. It is super great! Do you think much modular code just in case you have a hundreds of colors. You initiate `var` for each objects or you wrote switch case for each case.

Comment: I would have used an array instead of separate variables `stats1`, `stats2`, and so on. In general, whenever you find yourself naming variables like that, you should probably be using an array instead.

Comment: I just figured the answer would be easier to understand if I didn't complicate it with that change as well. I assumed if you just had three variables, you only had a fixed number of colors.

Comment: Could u please provide me a modular answer if you have it now.?

Comment: @ilyasUyanik Are you planning on having SO write your whole application for you? It seems like you're not making any attempt to figure this out on your own, you're just posting your requirements and expecting us to do it. Surely my answer to this question should give you ideas about how to solve the other question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` to obtain three separate arrays:

```
stats1 = stats.filter(function(x){return x.clr=="blue"});
stats2 = stats.filter(function(x){return x.clr=="yellow"});
stats3 = stats.filter(function(x){return x.clr=="green"});
```

then add the last element of the previous array to the next one with `splice`

```
stats2.splice(0,0,stats1[stats1.length-1]);
stats3.splice(0,0,stats2[stats2.length-1]);
```

then change the color of the first element of arrays `stats2` and `stats3`

```
stats2[0].clr="yellow";
stats3[0].clr="green";
```

Answer (score 1):

---

**UPDATE:** I've updated the solution to have the ability to connect last elements to form a link

---

I present a generic solution that allows you to split the array irrespective of which colors are part of the stats array.

```js
var stats = [
    {x: 10,  y: 300, clr:'blue'},
    {x: 16,  y: 600, clr:'blue'},
    {x: 26,  y: 300, clr:'yellow'},
    {x: 36,  y: 200, clr:'yellow'},
    {x: 46,  y: 700, clr:'green'},
    {x: 56,  y: 100, clr:'green'},
];
    
// the function receives the property with which you want to divide
// in our case, it is the 'clr' property
// the 'connectLast' boolean flag is used to connect the last link
var divideArrayByProperty = function(arr, property, connectLast) {
    
    var dividedArrays = {};
    var key = null;
    var lastElement = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        key = arr[i][property];
        if (undefined === dividedArrays[key]) {
            dividedArrays[key] = [];
            if (connectLast === true && i > 0) {
                lastElement = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr[i-1]));
                lastElement.clr = key;
                dividedArrays[key].push(lastElement);
            }
        }
        dividedArrays[key].push(arr[i]);
    }

    return dividedArrays;
};

var result = divideArrayByProperty(stats, 'clr', true);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<div id='output'></div>
```

Comment: it is great solution, but it does not take into account of last element appending. It returns 2 objects for each. Please check my output in the question. I have upvoted for the great answer.

Comment: @ilyasUyanik I've updated the solution to have the ability to connect last elements to form a link

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution.

```
var stats = [
{x: 10,  y: 300, clr:'blue'},
{x: 16,  y: 600, clr:'blue'},
{x: 26,  y: 300, clr:'yellow'},
{x: 36,  y: 200, clr:'yellow'},
{x: 46,  y: 700, clr:'green'},
{x: 56,  y: 100, clr:'green'},
];

function groupWith(arr, f) {
  var result = [], group = [];
  arr.forEach(function(elem) {
    if(group.length !== 0 && !f(group[group.length - 1], elem)) {
      result.push(group);
      group = [];
    }
    group.push(elem);
  });
  result.push(group);
  return result;
}

function getLast(array) {
  return array[array.length - 1];
}

function copyObject(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

var statsGrouped = groupWith(stats, function(a, b) {return a.clr === b.clr});
for(var i = 1; i < statsGrouped.length; i++) {
  statsGrouped[i].unshift(copyObject(getLast(statsGrouped[i-1])));
  statsGrouped[i][0].clr = statsGrouped[i][1].clr;
}

console.log(statsGrouped);
```