# Mapping- Separate Javascript Objects and then Append the Last Object

Tags: javascript, algorithm

There is a quite bit challenge to handle the following problem.

I have the following array and javascript objects:

**Input:**

I have three different colors `(blue,green,yellow)` and three different sizes `(sz=9,11,13)` in the javascript objects and trying to map them.

```
color=["blue","green","yellow"];

myObj=[{x:0,y:1,sz:9},{x:4,y:11,sz:9},{x:11,y:17,sz:11},{x:29,y:18,sz:13}];
```

**Output:**

```
data1:[{x:0,y:1,sz:9,color:"blue"},{x:4,y:11,sz:9,color:"blue"}];
data2:[{x:4,y:11,sz:9,color:"green"},{x:11,y:17,sz:11,color:"green"}];
data3:[{x:11,y:17,sz:11,color:"yellow"},{x:29,y:18,sz:13,color:"yellow"}];
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1b51eqoq/3/) which map objects based on their `sz` property and adds `color` properties. The only thing is missing is to add the last object and change  color.

For example:

`data2`'s first object comes from `data1`'s last object except different color which is green.

Here is what I have :

`data2:[{x:11,y:17,sz:11,color:"green"}];`

Here is what I need :

`data2:[{x:4,y:11,sz:9,color:"green"},{x:11,y:17,sz:11,color:"green"}];`

Comment: What do you mean, "*sort them based on their predefined size array*"? Why not just sort by their `.sz` property? And isn't that array already sorted?

Comment: `size` array actually could be also used to sort the object based on its `s` property.

Comment: I don't get it yet, I don't see any sorting in that fiddle. Do you want `color[size.indexOf(obj.sz)]`? Or do you have a problem constructing that `indices` object from `sizes`?

Comment: actually may be different terminology required rather than sorting maybe separation of data based on `size` Here is the simple version of my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vbLz9zc9/4/ First I am seperating javaobjects based on their sizes; however there are intermediate steps which is appending the last object to the first object with different color.

Comment: And now you ask how to do that programmatically? I miss an actual question in your post :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like that:

Sorry for that, i deleted the old code.

**UPDATE 3:**

https://jsfiddle.net/kxhsapad/3/

**OLD REQUEST:**

```
var size = [9, 11, 13, 15];
var colorA = ["blue", "green", "yellow", "red"];

var myObj = [{x:0,y:1,sz:9},{x:4,y:11,sz:9},{x:11,y:17,sz:11},{x:29,y:18,sz:13},{x:39,y:15,sz:15}];
var d1 = [];
var d2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < size.length; i++) {

    d1 = [];  
    d1[0] = myObj[i];
    d1[0].color = colorA[i];
    d1[1] = myObj[i + 1];
    d1[1].color = colorA[i];
    d2.push(d1);
}
for (var i = 0; i < d2.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < d2[i].length; j++) {
        var html = '<div id="' + i + '_' + j + '"';
        if (j%2==0) html += ' style="float:left;"';
        html += '>x=' + d2[i][j].x + ';y=' + d2[i][j].y + ';sz=' + d2[i][j].sz + ';color=' + d2[i][j].color + ';</div>';
        $('#container').append(html);
    }
}
```

Please check jsfiddle for full code https://jsfiddle.net/kxhsapad/

Comment: Could u please give jsfiddle or jsbin to test?

Comment: Line 3 there is an error, since 2d is `undefined`, also, you are pushing object references so if you modify one color, you modify them all at the same time.

Comment: @ilyasUyanik, i've pasted a new code, deleted the old one because i've made a mistake. Sorry for that

Comment: @Orchun, it is very close. If you take a look at the appending object color changes accordingly. Please watch color changes,  `data1` last object `{x:4,y:11,sz:9,color:"blue"}` appending to `data2` object `{x:4,y:11,sz:9,color:"green"}`

Comment: @ilyasUyanik, you've changed what you need. I'm not going to do it again. It's bed time :P

Comment: @Orchun, I have not changed anything except make the question simple. This requirement is there since I posted the question. You should not go to bed unless handle this trick! :P

Comment: @ilyasUyanik, if you didn't solve the problem yet. It's above, under update 3.