# Remove property in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following object

```
b.push({ data: d, width: 5, color: color });
```

then I have

```
b= [{data:10,width:5, color:"yellow"},{data:12,width:5, color:"red"},etc...];
```

I added `color` property and now I do not need and I want to remove it. I would like to know what is easiest way to do it?

Comment: You need to first [find that individual object within `b`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property). Then, you can `delete` `color` from it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can delete it using delete

```
delete b[0].color
```

Comment: Bu i have an array of objects pushed in the b.

Comment: @ilyasUyanik: So use a loop...?

Comment: Provide a better dataset @ilyasUyanik...

Comment: Please see updated. I know to iterate will work. Is there a way to make it better? I believe there should be alternative.

Comment: @ilyasUyanik: Why do you think there should be an alternative?

Comment: I am thinking there should be a inbuilt method in js to handle it rather than putting it in the loop.

Comment: @ilyasUyanik: There isn't. Use forEach or a for loop.

Comment: @ilyasUyanik: A loop *is* the built-in method to process a list of item.

Comment: Thanks Felix and Matti and Brendan, ok then if you think it is a that way, I will mark as answer. Sometimes I am thinking out of box maybe. It would better to be in the box. I always look to make it better if there is an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `.push({})` and pushing an object literal and not having reference any other way to those objects just use map:

```
b = b.map(function(obj) {
  return {data: obj.data, width: obj.width};
});
```

If you happen to have reference then the only way I can really think of it would be to use the `delete` keyword even though I don't recommend it:

```
for(var obj of b) {
  delete obj.color;
}
```

Comment: Prefer a normal `for` loop to iterate over an array.

Comment: Well depends if you're trying to suppor `IE` then perhaps, but a modern browser I'd use `for-of`

Comment: Believe it or not, I missed the `of` and thought it was a `for/in` loop. I agree, for the future, `for/of` is probably the way to go (even though I don't think it can achieve the performance of a `for` loop).

Comment: @FelixKling you do know `for of` is new, it's part of `ES6` and it's not just for arrays. It's for anything that's iterable, `arrays`, `strings`, `maps`, `sets` anything with a `[Symbol.iterator]` correctly implemented on. http://www.2ality.com/2013/06/iterators-generators.html

Comment: and V8 optimizes `for-of` also there's was some news I don't remember where there's an article that now `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {}` and `for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {}` are both just as fast.

Comment: Sure, I know what `for/of` does. But that's the thing: Because it works for *any* iterable, I can't imagine that it achieves the same performance for arrays as a for loop. But sure, engines might be able to optimize that (eventually) *"V8 optimizes for-of"* Source? Would love to read more about that.

Comment: Yes it's just as fast or perhaps fasater think about it a normal `for loop`: `for([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression]) { statements }` so first it has to initialize all variables, check condition, then after the final expresson. In for of all it has to do is check if iterable then check if `{done: true}` which would be always the same for any iterable. Compare to a conditon which it has no idea what it will be. I think it depends how you look at it. I can't seem to find the article on the optimization

Comment: Well, the check may be easier, but it has to call the `.next()` method of the iterator, and the iterator has to create a new object in every iteration. The loop also has to take into account that `.next` may throw an exception. All that sounds more expensive to me than a simple property access (`arr[i]`) (in comparison, [this is what Babel converts `for/of` into](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=for%20(var%20foo%20of%20bar)%20%7B%0A%0A%7D) ). But yeah, it's pretty much all speculation at this point and irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to find all objects where they have a property and that property has a targeted values that you want to delete.\

The program is pretty self-explanatory. Add a comment if you are missing a concept.

```js
/* Redirect console output to HTML. */ document.body.innerHTML = '';
console.log=function(){document.body.innerHTML+=[].slice.apply(arguments).join(' ')+'\n';};

var b = [{
  data: 'Red',
  width: 1,
  color: '#FF0000'
}, {
  data: 'Blue',
  width : 1,
  color: '#00FF00'
}, {
  data: 'Green',
  width: 1,
  color: '#0000FF'
}];

function removeProperty(items, key, value, propToRemove) {
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item != null && item[key] === value) {
      delete item[propToRemove];
    }
  });
}

// delete the 'color' property of the provided data matches.
removeProperty(b, 'data', 'Blue', 'color');

console.log(JSON.stringify(b, null, '  '));
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace; white-space: pre; font-size: 11px; }
```

Comment: Why the `!= null` bit? This way you can't match falsey values. In fact why test in the first place, I thought OP wanted to remove props from all objects.

Comment: It tests whether the object even has the property. It is similar to item.hasOwnProperty('key').

Comment: Similar, but not the same. What's the reason to have it in the first place?