# How to add new key-value pair under Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
[{"name":"Top Level","parent":"null"}]
```

Required output:

```
[{
"name": "Top Level",
"parent": "null",
"children": [
{
  "New_Key":"New_value"
}
]
}]
```

How can I add `"New_Key":"New_value"` pair under `"parent"` key?

Comment: `obj[0].children = [{"New_Key":"New_value"}]`

Comment: @Sooraj T, Please use google to search. Break down your problem and find solution individually and try to merge them.

Comment: **First step:** - [How to add key value pair to object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object). **Second Step:** Now all I need is *how to* [get object from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property) to add values. And Ta-Da!!

Answer (score -1):

its very simple, you can add any new item like obj["key"] = value, in your case you can do it like below

```
var arrObj = [{"name":"Top Level","parent":"null"}];
for(var i=0; i<arrObj.length; i++){
        arrObj[i].children = [{"New_Key":"New_value"}]
```

Comment: Not my downvote, just an observation, naming the full array `obj` is a bit counter-intuitive to my eyes

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = [{"name":"Top Level","parent":"null"}];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    arr[i].children = [{
                        "New_Key":"New_value"
                      }];
}
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but IMHO very likely because the downvoter thinks the question shouldnt *be answered*. They are expressing that we shouldnt encourage these types of questions (just answer in a comment and close the question), not saying your answer is wrong. I agree with the sentiment, but wouldnt downvote for it myself...

Comment: Not my vote, but should you not add explanation to your answer? Remember, its an answer for **readers** and not just **OP**. Also, questions that are very basic should not be answered. Since you know the solution, find relevant post and share it as a comment. This way, you'll help more people.