# Get index of array's object item by property and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm having troubles with updating found object.
I also tried [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects) and [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property)

Please help.

```js
// Create array
var schedule = [];
schedule.push({ 'action': 'add', 'id': 1 });
schedule.push({ 'action': 'update', 'id': 2 });

// Find array object
var searchId = 2;
var foundObj = schedule.filter(function(obj) { return obj.id == searchId; })

// Update found object
if (typeof foundObj !== 'undefined') {
  var newId = 3;
  schedule[foundObj] = {'action': 'delete', 'id': newId };
}

console.log(schedule);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: foundObj will be array and not the index what do you want ?

Comment: My question was hidden inside the code snippet. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use find to get the object and then use index of found object to replace element

```js
// Create array
var schedule = [];
schedule.push({ 'action': 'add', 'id': 1 });
schedule.push({ 'action': 'update', 'id': 2 });

// Find array object
var searchId = 2;
var foundObj = schedule.find(function(obj) { return obj.id == searchId; })
// Update found object
if (typeof foundObj !== 'undefined') {
  var newId = 3;
  schedule[schedule.indexOf(foundObj )] = {'action': 'delete', 'id': newId };
}

console.log(schedule);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You already filtered the element, so you can update it directly instead of re-searching for its index

Comment: Yup, that's right - But at least you're demonstrating 2  possible solutions

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and check and update the properties.

```js
var schedule = [{ action: 'add', id: 1 }, { action: 'update', id: 2 }],
    searchId = 2,
    newId = 3,
    foundObj = schedule.find(function(obj) { return obj.id == searchId; })

if (foundObj) {
    foundObj.action = 'delete';
    foundObj.id = newId;
}

console.log(schedule);
```