# Get the value of the data based on the `id` with ajax json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have data with json format, and I tried to show her with ajax and successfully. but how to find one `id` in json using ajax? and whether the script I got it right? example I want to find id `2`.

My json

```
{ "device": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Android"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Apel"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Windows"
    }
] }
```

My ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id_pm = 2 ;
    var dataString = "id="+id_pm;   
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.json",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 3000,
        error: function(){
            alert('Error');
        },              
        success: function(result){
            var result=$.parseJSON(result);
            $.each(result, function(i, element){        
                var id=element.id;
                var name=element.name;  
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: *"and whether the script I got it right?"* - Well, what happened when you ran it?

Comment: yes I expected how to look for `id` = 2 of data.json without using the query url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value or property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id's are meant to be unique.If your JSON does not contain sequential id's  then you will have to sequentially scan all the objects like this :

```
//put this inside your success callback.
var mysearchId = 2;
//res is now array of all your devices.
var res = (JSON.parse(result)).device;
for(var i = 0;i < res.length;i ++) {
    if(res[i].id == mysearchId) {
      console.log(res[i]);
      return;
    }
}
console.log('not found!');
```

This finds the desired item in O(N) time.

In case your id's are sequential you can find a particular element in O(1) time.To achieve this,the devices array must be sorted.
For example if you want to find element with id 10 you can access it by `res[(10-1)]; //==>res[9];` provided the first item has id=1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function to filter the data based on id

```
var data = {
            "device": [
         {
             "id": 1,
             "name": "Android"
         },
         {
             "id": 2,
             "name": "Apel"
         },
         {
             "id": 3,
             "name": "Windows"
         }
            ]
        };

        var res = data.device.filter(function (obj) {
            return obj.id == 2;
        });

 if(res.length){
  console.log(res[0].id);
  console.log(res[0].name);
}
```

Comment: `Array.find` would suit more

Comment: Also should you not close the question as duplicate as there are many posts on *getting object based on key*?

Comment: @Mairaj, thanks for answer, but my data in a file on the url ex.`http: //project/data.json`