# Array.find searching by a specific value

Tags: javascript

i have a local variable that i want to find by him ..

```html
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
var ages = [{a:"danielhason",b:"1"},{a:"aanielhason",b:"2"},{a:"banielhason",b:"3"),{a:"zanielhason",b:"4"}];
var z = "1";

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (ages.find(function (age) { return age == z;})).a;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value or property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ages` is an array of objects, you have to iterate over it. Let's say that `v` is every object inside `ages` array. Then, you have to use a condition, if `v.b` is equal to `z` value (1) - log that object `a` value - `v.a`.

**Note**: Keep your code clean, use line breaks.

```js
var ages = [{
  a: "danielhason",
  b: "1"
}, {
  a: "aanielhason",
  b: "2"
}, {
  a: "banielhason",
  b: "3",
}, {
  a: "zanielhason",
  b: "4"
}];

function myFunction(ages) {
  var z = "1";
  ages.find(function(v) {
    if (v.b == z) {
      console.log(v.a)
    }
  })
}

myFunction(ages);
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(ages)">Try it</button>
```

Comment: the problam is that its not letting me have z value in the func

Comment: @DanielHas Then put it inside the function body. I've edited my answer. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
var ages = [{a:"danielhason",b:"1"},{a:"aanielhason",b:"2"},{a:"banielhason",b:"3"),{a:"zanielhason",b:"4"}];
var z = "1";

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (ages.find(function (age) { return age.b == z;})).a;
}
</script>

</body>
```

You just needed to add `.b` to your find age.

Comment: nop its not working , its something about the Array.find. idk why its like that

Answer (score 0):

I mean, there are a couple of issues here, but the first one I noticed was this line:

```
 document.getElementById("demo")
```

You have no element with the `id` "demo".

Smit's answer below is also correct.  There were multiple issues here.