# Convert JSON data to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

My json data is like that:

```
[{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"R90N8E95UB"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Honda","model":"Accord","vin":"XJLSXU6NA5"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"2UNHFBCQG0"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC90","vin":"J37612ZVEC"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"OB60BC33LF"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC90","vin":"DCA3364SGK"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC60","vin":"FV2HML056G"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"BMW","model":"328xi","vin":"IGPP3DQ4SK"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Honda","model":"Accord","vin":"XJLSXU6NA5"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"R90N8E95UB"}]
```

Now I want my array to be like this in JavaScript:

```
// Javascript array
var array = [];
array[// vin number od above json array] = // the whole row of that vin number.
```

For example.,

```
// Javascript array
array["R90N8E95UB"][0] 
=[{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"R90N8E95UB"}]
array["R90N8E95UB"][1] 
=[{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"R90N8E95UB"}]
```

And so on...

Please advice on it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could iterate and push to the inner array.

```js
var data = [{ vehicleType: "car", make: "Dodge", model: "Durango", vin: "R90N8E95UB" }, { vehicleType: "car", make: "Honda", model: "Accord", vin: "XJLSXU6NA5" }, { vehicleType: "car", make: "Dodge", model: "Durango", vin: "2UNHFBCQG0" }, { vehicleType: "car", make: "Volvo", model: "XC90", vin: "J37612ZVEC" }, { vehicleType: "car", make: "Mercedes", model: "C250", vin: "J5QB24CFGS" }, { vehicleType: "car", make: "Dodge", model: "Durango", vin: "OB60BC33LF" }, { vehicleType: "car", make: "Volvo", model: "XC90", vin: "DCA3364SGK" }, { vehicleType: "car", make: "Volvo", model: "XC60", vin: "FV2HML056G" }, { vehicleType: "car", make: "BMW", model: "328xi", vin: "IGPP3DQ4SK" }, { vehicleType: "car", make: "Mercedes", model: "C250", vin: "J5QB24CFGS" }, { vehicleType: "car", make: "Honda", model: "Accord", vin: "XJLSXU6NA5" }, { vehicleType: "car", make: "Mercedes", model: "C250", vin: "J5QB24CFGS" }, { vehicleType: "car", make: "Dodge", model: "Durango", vin: "R90N8E95UB" }],
    result = Object.create(null),
    keys;

data.forEach(function (a) {
    result[a.vin] = result[a.vin] || [];
    result[a.vin].push(a);
});

keys = Object.keys(result);

console.log(keys);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi @Nina,
I also want all key of that unique vin number.
Can you please help me for the same?
For ex., var keys = ["R90N8E95UB","XJLSXU6NA5","2UNHFBCQG0",...]

Comment: That would be awesome @NinaScholz.
Thank you so much  for help.

Answer (score 5):

```js
var json = [{vehicleType:"car",make:"Dodge",model:"Durango",vin:"R90N8E95UB"},{vehicleType:"car",make:"Honda",model:"Accord",vin:"XJLSXU6NA5"},{vehicleType:"car",make:"Dodge",model:"Durango",vin:"2UNHFBCQG0"},{vehicleType:"car",make:"Volvo",model:"XC90",vin:"J37612ZVEC"},{vehicleType:"car",make:"Mercedes",model:"C250",vin:"J5QB24CFGS"},{vehicleType:"car",make:"Dodge",model:"Durango",vin:"OB60BC33LF"},{vehicleType:"car",make:"Volvo",model:"XC90",vin:"DCA3364SGK"},{vehicleType:"car",make:"Volvo",model:"XC60",vin:"FV2HML056G"},{vehicleType:"car",make:"BMW",model:"328xi",vin:"IGPP3DQ4SK"},{vehicleType:"car",make:"Mercedes",model:"C250",vin:"J5QB24CFGS"},{vehicleType:"car",make:"Honda",model:"Accord",vin:"XJLSXU6NA5"},{vehicleType:"car",make:"Mercedes",model:"C250",vin:"J5QB24CFGS"},{vehicleType:"car",make:"Dodge",model:"Durango",vin:"R90N8E95UB"}],
    result = [];
 
    json.forEach(v => result.push([v.vin, v]));
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: I wish you hadn't deleted your answer to "that other question" today - it was different and it worked -- and that made it valuable. As for the problem of drive-by downvoters on SO, I was going to add this: Downvoting on SO is a lot like what is often said about Democracy - that it is the best form of government in the world EXCEPT FOR that stupid part about letting just anyone (down)vote.

Answer (score 2):

In ES2015:
var arr = Object.values(obj);

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps :

```js
var arr = {};
var pop = [{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"R90N8E95UB"},{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Honda","model":"Accord","vin":"XJLSXU6NA5"},{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"2UNHFBCQG0"},{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC90","vin":"J37612ZVEC"},{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"OB60BC33LF"},{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC90","vin":"DCA3364SGK"},{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC60","vin":"FV2HML056G"},{"vehicleType":"car","make":"BMW","model":"328xi","vin":"IGPP3DQ4SK"},{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Honda","model":"Accord","vin":"XJLSXU6NA5"},{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"R90N8E95UB"}];
pop.forEach(function(item){
  if ( arr[item.vin] ) {   
   arr[item.vin].push([item]);
  } else {
    arr[item.vin] = [[item]];
  }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr["R90N8E95UB"][0]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr["R90N8E95UB"][1]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var yourData = [{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"R90N8E95UB"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Honda","model":"Accord","vin":"XJLSXU6NA5"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"2UNHFBCQG0"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC90","vin":"J37612ZVEC"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"OB60BC33LF"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC90","vin":"DCA3364SGK"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC60","vin":"FV2HML056G"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"BMW","model":"328xi","vin":"IGPP3DQ4SK"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Honda","model":"Accord","vin":"XJLSXU6NA5"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"R90N8E95UB"}];


 var result = yourData.reduce(function (acc,curr) {
    acc[curr.vin]= acc[curr.vin] || [];
    acc[curr.vin].push(curr);
    return acc;
},{});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var data = [{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"R90N8E95UB"},
        {"vehicleType":"car","make":"Honda","model":"Accord","vin":"XJLSXU6NA5"},
        {"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"2UNHFBCQG0"},
        {"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC90","vin":"J37612ZVEC"},
        {"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},
        {"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"OB60BC33LF"},
        {"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC90","vin":"DCA3364SGK"},
        {"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC60","vin":"FV2HML056G"},
        {"vehicleType":"car","make":"BMW","model":"328xi","vin":"IGPP3DQ4SK"},
        {"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},
        {"vehicleType":"car","make":"Honda","model":"Accord","vin":"XJLSXU6NA5"},
        {"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},
        {"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"R90N8E95UB"}];



        var array = [];
        for(var k= 0 ,l = data.length;k<l;k++){
            array[data[k].vin] = data[k];       
        }
        console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply assign it to something?

```
var array =    [{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"R90N8E95UB"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Honda","model":"Accord","vin":"XJLSXU6NA5"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"2UNHFBCQG0"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC90","vin":"J37612ZVEC"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"OB60BC33LF"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC90","vin":"DCA3364SGK"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Volvo","model":"XC60","vin":"FV2HML056G"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"BMW","model":"328xi","vin":"IGPP3DQ4SK"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Honda","model":"Accord","vin":"XJLSXU6NA5"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250","vin":"J5QB24CFGS"},
{"vehicleType":"car","make":"Dodge","model":"Durango","vin":"R90N8E95UB"}]
```

Then

```
array[0]:
Object {vehicleType: "car", make: "Dodge", model: "Durango", vin: "R90N8E95UB"}
```

But if you need to lookup a car based on their vin, make the vin the key and the variable needs to be an object, not an array.

```
var object = {"R90N8E95UB": {"vehicleType": "car", make: "Dodge", model: "Durango"},
              "J5QB24CFGS": {"vehicleType":"car","make":"Mercedes","model":"C250"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object the way you showed, you can get an array by Object.values()

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data IS already an array. One way to get the data can be found at [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property)
There you can found a way to query your JSON Array.