# How to search an array of objects for a specific object property

Tags: angularjs, web-applications

Below is the link of my code:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDTQ99YQS60B

How do I get users to only be able to buy 2 players the position "Defender"? Put another way, how do I get users to only be able to buy 2 Objects of each position?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value or property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `Array.prototype.reduce` to solve your issue. Hope this helps.

```
var selected = $scope.history.reduce(function(a,b){
    a[b.position] = (a[b.position] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
}, {}) || {};

//{defender:1, forward: 2, midfielder:1}
```

This block calculate the added counts for each player positions. if no players added, then `selected` would default to `{}`. Also, I'm passing `player` object instead of `$index` to `buy` method.

So, the below condition checks the number of players added for each player position.

```
if(!selected[player.position] || selected[player.position]<2){
    $scope.history.push(player);
}else{
    alert('You can add only two players per position');
}
```

here `player.position` is from the `player` object passed to `buy` method.

So, let say,

```
selected = {defender:1, forward: 2, midfielder:1};
```

and `player` passsed to `buy` method as,

```
player = {name : "Chinedu 'Anuxx' Anukwem", Team : "FBGFC", price: 8000000, position:'forward',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'};

console.log(selected[player.position]) // 2
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, PlayerService) {
    $scope.playersSelected = "0/6";
    $scope.total = 50000000;
    //keep trak of what was bought already
    $scope.history = PlayerService.getSelectedPlayers();
    $scope.denteries = [];
    $scope.players = [{
        name: "Yasin 'YB' Amusan",
        Team: "Industry",
        price: 8000000,
        position: 'forward',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Hassan 'Hasi' Akinyera",
        Team: "Industry",
        price: 5000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Femi 'Fabio' Awoniyi",
        Team: "Industry",
        price: 9000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Deji 'Dej' Awoniyi",
        Team: "Industry",
        price: 7000000,
        position: 'forward',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Koye 'K10' Kekere-Ekun",
        Team: "Industry",
        price: 9000000,
        position: 'midfielder',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Teni 'Teezee' Zacchaeus",
        Team: "Industry",
        price: 6000000,
        position: 'hybrid',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Bolaji 'Boj' Odojukan",
        Team: "Industry",
        price: 7000000,
        position: 'forward',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Ernest",
        Team: "Industry",
        price: 6000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Fikayo 'Kyo' Etti",
        Team: "Industry",
        price: 8000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Efe Tunde-Imoyo",
        Team: "Industry",
        price: 5000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Temi 'Forbes' Afolabi",
        Team: "VGC",
        price: 14000000,
        position: 'forward',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Dami Etomi",
        Team: "VGC",
        price: 7000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Tomi 'Belg' Belgore",
        Team: "VGC",
        price: 8000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Tobi 'Staxx' Kasali",
        Team: "VGC",
        price: 9000000,
        position: 'Hybrid',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Bobo",
        Team: "VGC",
        price: 9000000,
        position: 'Hybrid',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Ola Adeyemi",
        Team: "VGC",
        price: 5000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Pekun 'Pyzzle' Odutola",
        Team: "VGC",
        price: 9000000,
        position: 'Hybrid',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Oreva 'Revz' Amata",
        Team: "VGC",
        price: 11000000,
        position: 'forward',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Tenny 'TK' Karim",
        Team: "YMFC",
        price: 5000000,
        position: 'Forward',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Andy Inegbese",
        Team: "YMFC",
        price: 5000000,
        position: 'Midfielder',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Donald 'DO' Ofik",
        Team: "YMFC",
        price: 7000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Zachy Mbadiwe",
        Team: "YMFC",
        price: 10000000,
        position: 'Forward',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Emeke 'Mexxo'",
        Team: "YMFC",
        price: 6000000,
        position: 'midfielder',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Ife 'I-Baxx Bakare",
        Team: "YMFC",
        price: 6000000,
        position: 'midfielder',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Gabriel 'Gabby' Inegbese",
        Team: "YMFC",
        price: 8000000,
        position: 'Hybrid',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Jimi Oyelola",
        Team: "YMFC",
        price: 5000000,
        position: 'Forward',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Chad 'Chadea' Oyefolu",
        Team: "ChadFC",
        price: 5000000,
        position: 'Forward',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Ekoh 'Starboy' Sagoe",
        Team: "ChadFC",
        price: 15000000,
        position: 'midfielder',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Tomiwa 'JBET' Jaiyeola",
        Team: "ChadFC",
        price: 13000000,
        position: 'Forward',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Lemar Chris",
        Team: "ChadFC",
        price: 9000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Olumide 'Olic' Williams",
        Team: "ChadFC",
        price: 7000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Leke 'LVD' Dokomu",
        Team: "ChadFC",
        price: 7000000,
        position: 'midfielder',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Dola Awosika",
        Team: "ChadFC",
        price: 5000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Nehemiah 'Memphis'",
        Team: "ChadFC",
        price: 7000000,
        position: 'midfielder',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Kola 'Skippo' Ayanwale",
        Team: "ChadFC",
        price: 10000000,
        position: 'midfielder',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Milekan 'Mileks'",
        Team: "ChadFC",
        price: 7000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Lanre 'Lavigz' Vigo",
        Team: "ChadFC",
        price: 8000000,
        position: 'hybrid',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Alfred 'Flyz' Obande",
        Team: "FBGFC",
        price: 6000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Chuka 'Zingy' Azinge",
        Team: "FBGFC",
        price: 6000000,
        position: 'hybrid',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Osobase 'Oso' OmoKhodion",
        Team: "FBGFC",
        price: 10000000,
        position: 'midfielder',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Arnold Okuguni",
        Team: "FBGFC",
        price: 7000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Ikenna Mbadiwe",
        Team: "FBGFC",
        price: 6000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Moukhtar",
        Team: "FBGFC",
        price: 8000000,
        position: 'forward',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Chinedu 'Anuxx' Anukwem",
        Team: "FBGFC",
        price: 8000000,
        position: 'forward',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Tosan 'Mac' Wiltshere",
        Team: "FBGFC",
        price: 6000000,
        position: 'defender',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      },
      {
        name: "Martin Agbaso",
        Team: "FBGFC",
        price: 5000000,
        position: 'forward',
        image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
      }
    ];

    $scope.buy = function(player) {
      //remove if already added
      if(PlayerService.removePlayerFromSelection(player)){
        return;
      }

      //max 6 allowed
      if ($scope.history.length >= 6) {
        alert('max 6 allowed');
        return;
      }

      var selected = $scope.history.reduce(function(a, b) {
        a[b.position] = (a[b.position] || 0) + 1;
        return a;
      }, {}) || {};

      if (!selected[player.position] || selected[player.position] < 2) {
        PlayerService.addPlayerToSelection(player);
      } else {
        alert('You can add only two players per position');
      }
    };

    $scope.getTotal = function() {
      return $scope.history.reduce(function(tot, p) {
        tot = tot - p.price;
        return tot;
      }, $scope.total);
    };
  })
  .factory('PlayerService', function() {
    var service = {};
    var _data = {
      selectedPlayers: []
    };

    service.getSelectedPlayers = function() {
      return _data.selectedPlayers;
    };

    service.setSelectedPlayers = function(players) {
      //to maintain the array reference we are doing this, othewise we can directly assign players to selectedPlayers
      _data.selectedPlayers.splice(0, _data.selectedPlayers.length);
      players.forEach(function(player) {
        _data.selectedPlayers.push(player);
      });
    };

    service.addPlayerToSelection = function(player) {
      return _data.selectedPlayers.push(player);
    };

    service.removePlayerFromSelection = function(player) {
      var index = _data.selectedPlayers.indexOf(player);
      if (index >= 0) {
        _data.selectedPlayers.splice(index, 1);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    };

    return service;
  })
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, PlayerService){
    $scope.selectedPlayers = PlayerService.getSelectedPlayers();
  });
```

```css
div[ng-controller]{
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>TNF FANTASY</title>
</head>


<div class="app" ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div class="total"><i>  <h4> Money Remaining: <br>{{getTotal() |currency}}</h4></i>
    <h4>{{history.length}}/6</h4>

  </div>

  <ul>
    <li class="players" ng-repeat="player in players">


      {{player.name}} <br> {{player.Team}} <br> {{player.price| currency}} <br> {{player.position| uppercase }}
      <br>
      <button ng-click="buy(player)">{{history.indexOf(player)>=0?'remove':'buy'}}</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <h1>Selected player accessed in another controller:</h1>
    
    <pre>{{selectedPlayers | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: YES!!!! Thanks and God bless. This was perfect. Do you mind explaining this a bit? I spent the past 2 and a half days trying to work this out. @ajaiJothi

Comment: Updated. Hope this helps :)

Comment: It really does. It has broken it down perfectly. Last question: is it possible for the limit on player selection to apply to all positions bar the "hybrid" position? It works fine the way you've explained this is purely educational

Comment: Yes, you can have limits for each positions. eg: `var defaultCnt = 2; var limits = {hybrid:2, forward:3, defender:2};` and in condition check u can refer this limit with `if(!selected[player.position] || selected[player.position]<(limits[player.position]||defaultCnt))` instead of hardcoded count.

Comment: hey quick question. is there a way to access the selected players in another page? I tried routing to access the $scope.history array in the second page but nothing came up. I also tried a service but i'm not sure that works either.

Comment: Yes. You have to use a `service` for sharing objects between pages. One more way is there, you can save the selected object in `$rootScope` and access it in other pages. but I wont recommend this - it is like polluting global scope.

Comment: haha at this point i won't mind polluting. But i'll give services a try again. Do i need to create a service for each of my arrays? The json file i currently have made has both the 'players' array with the objects and the 'history' array that is empty into which selected players are pushed. This did not seem to work.

Comment: Updated the code with service implementation. Take a look :)

Comment: ah right Thanks a lot. Lemme have a look

Comment: so i ran the code but tried to modify it by moving the TestCtrl to anther page on my folder called #status and it did not work. But it revealed another flaw in my code: that the user's choices arent saved before moving to the next page. Thank You So much though

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is before adding the player to `$scope.history` array you check if that position already has to 2 players selected.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I am trying to do. But i am struggling to get right way to do this. I tried using indexOf but it did not work.

Comment: use `hasOwnProperty`