# How to check if an array object contains one string in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

this is my code i want to check that if array contains this specific string "Identicon". and i'm looking for one line code for as solution i just want to check with if condition.

```
 $scope.profileImageOptions = [
                      {
                Type: "Identicon",
                Code: "identicon"
            },
            {
                Type: "MonsterID",
                Code: "monsterid"
            },

        ];

    if($scope.profileImageOptions.indexOf($rootScope.settings.defaultImage) >-1)
{
    console.log('ok');

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value or property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property)

Comment: @Lakmi, it is working my solution ?

Comment: @Nguyen Thanh  NO because,  i'm looking for one line code. I got solution from this post. thnx

Comment: @Alexandru,  YES your solution working for me thnx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `includes` method in combination with `some` method.

`some` method accepts as parameter a `callback` provided function which is applied for every item in the `array`.

```js
profileImageOptions = [
            {
                Type: "Identicon",
                Code: "identicon"
            },
            {
                Type: "MonsterID",
                Code: "monsterid"
            },

];
var exist=profileImageOptions.some(function(item){
  return item.Type.includes("Identicon");
});
console.log(exist);
```

Also, you can use an `arrow function` to simplify your code.

```
profileImageOptions.some(item => item.Type.includes("Identicon"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [
                      {
                Type: "Identicon",
                Code: "identicon"
            },
            {
                Type: "MonsterID",
                Code: "monsterid"
            },

        ];
var result = arr.some(element => element.Type.includes('Identicon'));
console.log(result)
```

Let's use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example) in Javascript:

```
$scope.profileImageOptions.some(element => element.Type.includes('Identicon'));
```

Comment: Thnak you for help.

Comment: Glad to know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

<p>The name is {{ result[0].Type == "Identicon" ? "OK" : "Not OK"}}</p>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.profileImageOptions = [
                      {
                Type: "Identicon",
                Code: "identicon"
            },
            {
                Type: "MonsterID",
                Code: "monsterid"
            },

        ];

        $scope.result = $scope.profileImageOptions.filter(function(res){
        return res.Type ==  "Identicon";});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Check the [example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEZ5666UC8ZR)