# Angular Typescript - return number of objects satisfying a constraint from an Array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to do something similar to LINQ in C# with a list I have in TypeScript.
Basically, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
numberOfObjectsSatisfyingConstraint: number = 
this.objectsToSearch.(/* This is the part I can't figure out. */).length;
```

Comment: You might check it [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property). I believe it answers your question

Comment: See the answer on Array filter below. Just keep in mind it creates a new array.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using the following:

```
`this.objectsToSearch.filter(s => s.<condition goes here>).length;`
```

Comment: That code could not possibly work due to the syntax error at `filter.(`...