# Get corresponding value from array for value passed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, loops, underscore.js

I have this array

```
var getDay: [
    { DayValue: '10D', DayDisplay: '10' },
    { DayValue: '20D', DayDisplay: '20' },
    { DayValue: '30D', DayDisplay: '30' }
      ]
```

Now there is another code as follows.

```
var b_day = getDayDetails('10D')
```

This will get 10D and check the corresponding DayDisplay value in getDay array.

I want the final value of b_day as '10'

Similarly, if `var b_day = getDayDetails('20D')`, i want the final value of b_day as '20'

can someone please let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: This is literally one line of code. What have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a filter:

```
function getDayDetails (input) {
    if(getDay.length) {
        var v = getDay.filter(function(element) {
            return element.DayValue === input;
        });
        if(v.length) return v[0].DayDisplay;
        else return null;
    } else return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `_.find` to achieve this

```
function getDayDetails(data){
    return _.find(getDay,{'DayValue':data});
}
function getDayDisplayDetails(data){
    return _.find(getDay,{'DayDisplay':data});
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/HePxjuAdkaJU1Ee5DtO3?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
function findDay(dayParam) {
    const day = getDay.find(day => day.DayValue == dayParam);
    return day && day.DayDisplay;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, there are a couple of ways this could be done. Probably the simplest (admittedly not the best) way would just be a FOR loop going through the array and checking the object's properties at each index until you hit upon the right one.

Something like this:

```
function getDayDetails (v) {
    for (var i in getDay) {
        if (getDay[i].DayValue === v) return getDay[i].DayDisplay;
    }
}
```

This could probably be tidied up a bit, but that seems to be the sort of thing you're after.