# Looping through an array of objects in typescript and get a specific fails using Es6 syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have several objects and i would like to get one and check a specific property

so i have

```
 data: [{is_guest: true},{permission:'is_allowed_ip'}]
```

Now when i check the `console.log(route.data)` am getting

```
0:{is_guest:true},
1:{permission:'is_allowed_ip' }
```

and `typeof route.data` is an object

now i would like to get the object with is_guest:true

So i have tried

```
   const data = Object.keys(route.data).map((index) => {
      if (route.data[index].is_guest) {
       return route.data[index]
      }
    });

  console.log("route data is",data)  //this still returns all the items
```

But the above fails returning all the objects.
How do i loop through all the objects and retrieve just only one with the is_guest key and value true

Comment: If it's always the first, just access it via `route.data[0].is_guest`

Comment: Do you not want `.filter` if you're trying to return a subset of the data?

Comment: @Zenoo some routes dont have the is_guest property so i cannot simply use the use an index.

Comment: @DanGamble with .filter am getting an error route.data.filter is not a function,   they are object not arrays.

Comment: *"But the above fails returning all the objects"* No, it returns matching objects and `undefined` for all others -- because `map` builds a new array with an entry for every entry in the original, based on what you return from the callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), not `Object.keys`, and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
const data = Object.values(route.data).filter(e => e.is_guest);
```

`Object.values` is fairly new, but present on up-to-date Node, and entirely polyfillable.

Example:

```js
const route = {
  data: [
    {is_guest: true},
    {permission:'is_allowed_ip'}
  ]
};
const data = Object.values(route.data).filter(e => e.is_guest);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: .values throws an error of unresolved variable values

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI: As I said above, it's relatively new and may need polyfilling.

Answer (score 0):

Using E6:

```
data.filter(o => o.is_guest)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

I added some ids into your array just to make easier to understand.

```js
// added ids to exemplify 
const data = [ 
  {id: 1, is_guest: true}, 
  {id: 2, permission:'is_allowed_ip'},
  {id: 3, is_guest: true}, 
  {id: 4, is_guest: false}, 
 ]

// filter results
const filtered = data.filter(item => item.is_guest)

// just to show the result
document.querySelector('.debug').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filtered, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre><code class="debug"></code></pre>
```