# how to access a JSON element when i have a value of another element in the same object?

Tags: javascript, json

Assume that i have this json obj:

```
var person=[{"name":"joe","age":21,"class":"a"},{"name":"moe","age":22,"class":"b"}];
```

i want to get the age of joe using given name which is **joe**.
is there something like this:
`var age = person.name['joe'].age`

Comment: You have an array, so you need to iterate the array and look for the object that has `name` of `joe`.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property) might be a better duplicate. The linked one (imo) is too broad and the solution to OP's question is not easily distilled from it's answers.

Comment: true, the answer is there, but i still believe that my question is much easier to read. thanks @Marcos Casagrande for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) to search for a specific property in an array of objects.

```js
var person=[{"name":"joe","age":21,"class":"a"},{"name":"moe","age":22,"class":"b"}];
    
const joe = person.find(item => item.name === 'joe');

if(joe)
   console.log(`Joe is ${joe.age} years old`);
```