# Finding the third element value in a dictionary

Tags: javascript

I need to find the third element of a dictionary array knowing the first two values. For example:

```
    var dict = [{name: "A", game: "X", number: 5},
               {name: "B", game: "X", number: 3},
               {name: "A", game: "Y", number: 1},
               {name: "C", game: "Z", number: 2}]
```

So if I find ***name: "A"*** and ***game: "X"*** this will return ***number: 5*** or just ***5***. And if it is posible, getting the index in the array of that element, for example in that case the index would be ***0*** because that is in ***dict[0]***

Comment: Did you try anything ? What part was a problem ?

Comment: `var dict = arr.find(x => x.name === 'A'  && x.game === 'X').number`. Note that JavaScript doesn't call them dictionaries.

Comment: It's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value of property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find()` method if you want to find specific object from array and return it.

```js
 var dict = [{name: "A", game: "X", number: 5}, {name: "B", game: "X", number: 3}, {name: "A", game: "Y", number: 1}, {name: "C", game: "Z", number: 2}]
               
const obj = dict.find(({name, game}) => name == 'A' && game == 'X');
if(obj) console.log(obj.number)
```

If you want to get index you can use `findIndex` method instead which is going to return index if element is found or -1 if not.

```js
 var dict = [{name: "A", game: "X", number: 5}, {name: "B", game: "X", number: 3}, {name: "A", game: "Y", number: 1}, {name: "C", game: "Z", number: 2}]
               
const index = dict.findIndex(({name, game}) => name == 'A' && game == 'X');
console.log(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

## ES6

You could use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method of array

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is returned.

**DEMO**

```js
const arr = [{name: "A", game: "X", number: 5},
{name: "B", game: "X", number: 3},
{name: "A", game: "Y", number: 1},
{name: "C", game: "Z", number: 2}];
               
let result = arr.find( ({ name, game }) => name=='A' && game=='X');               
               
if(result){
  console.log(result.number)
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstood your question. This is what you can try with [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
var dict = [{name: "A", game: "X", number: 5},
               {name: "B", game: "X", number: 3},
               {name: "A", game: "Y", number: 1},
               {name: "C", game: "Z", number: 2}];

//find other property value based on some property value
var find = dict.find(elm => elm.name ==='A' && elm.game==='X').number;

//find the index based on property value
var findIndex = dict.findIndex(elm => elm.name==='A' && elm.game==='X');

console.log(find);
console.log(findIndex);
```

Comment: @Yamika Izumi did you try what I've posted?