# How to select a Array index element with respect of its one of Value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Array

```
    var arr=[{t: "Lokanath", v: 0},
            {t: "Das", v: 1}]
```

Is there any way that i can get the Record `t: "Das", v: 1` based on the value of v `i.e. v:1`

Comment: `a.find(i => i.text === 'Das');`..?

Comment: Right, its a Generic way i have represented .

Comment: @lokanathdas, why downvotes to soln, pls explain ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value of property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property)

Comment: My target is if i get the a[1] item (i.e. {text: "Das", value: 1, id: 101}) i need to push to one more array for some other operation.

Comment: M not sure why i got 3 negative votes, where as the question was quite clear & has a valid reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

You can use `filter()` in the following way:

```js
var a=[{text: "Lokanath", value: 0, id: 100},
{text: "Das", value: 1, id: 101}];

var das = a.filter(p => p.text=='Das');
console.log(das[0]);
```

**Please Note:** Since `filter()` returns an array, you have to use index to take the object.

Comment: Why use jQuery? This is native JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr=[{text: "Lokanath", value: 0, id: 100},
            {text: "Das", value: 1, id: 101}]

arr.find(d => d.text == "Das")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -1):

you can use filter method to do that.

```
var arr=[{text: "Lokanath", value: 0, id: 100},{text: "Das", value: 1, id: 101}];
console.log(arr.filter(o => o.text=='Das')[0]);
```