# How to get value from JavaScript object when known associate element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I put in HTML

```
console.log(foo["_pristineData"]);
```

at console I see

[image]

`value` field is unique. I can get `value` filed by

```
document.getElementById("blablaInput").value;
```

it return `BAR` .

How to get text `Bar join stock company` based on `BAR` (what I can get)?

(Return a string, not an object like this question [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value of property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property) The question is not duplicate)

Comment: Its in `foo["_pristineData"][1].text` are you asking how to find the index, as thats 100% a dupe.

Comment: You mean you want to get value based on input value ?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't know how to get index what base-on `BAR`. I can get `BAR` right now, but I don't know how to get its index. Seemly, When I get index success, I can get its text.

Comment: @CodeManiac yes, I need return "Bar joint stock company" based-on `BAR` (field `value` is unique, it means 2 or many values are never duplicate.

Comment: Duplicate of [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value of property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property)

Comment: @DoNhuVy you can simply use `find` in this case as you have unique values, you don't need to find index explicitly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're field values are unique so You can use find and return values accordingly, in case you have multiple value and you want to capture all of them you can use `filter`

```js
const foo =[
  {value: 'FOO', text:'some text'},
  {value: 'BAR', text: 'Some bar text'}
]

const getValue = () =>{
  let value = document.getElementById('id_1').value
  let found = foo.find(v=> v.value === value)
  let final = found ? found.text : 'Not found'
  console.log(final)
}
```

```html
<input id='id_1' value=''></input>
<button onClick='getValue()'>Give me value</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `find`:

```js
const foo = {
  _pristineIndex: [{value: "FOO", text: "Foo limited liability company"},
{value: "BAR", text: "Bar joint stock company"},
{value: "", text: ""}]
};

const { text: res } = foo._pristineIndex.find(({ value }) => value == "BAR");

console.log(res);
```

Comment: It is quite near with my purpose. But I catch error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

Comment: `_pristineIndex` is what I don't know how to get, or I cannot get.

Comment: Try bracket notation: `foo["_pristineIndex"]`.

Comment: I also try `const { text: res } = foo["_pristineIndex"].find(({ value }) => value == "BAR");`    https://imgur.com/a/rp596Jj