# Is it better to store data as an object of objects where each key is an ID, or an array of objects where the ID is stored as a prop in each object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuex

I'm trying to figure out how to structure data that allows for easy and quick retrieval when given a lookup ID. There are two methods I'm considering:

**METHOD 1: An object of objects where each key is a lookup ID**

```js
const people1 = {
    1: {
        name: 'bob',
        weight: 180
    },
    25: {
        name: 'chris',
        gender: 'male'
    },
    127: {
        name: 'shannon',
        age: 43
    },
}
```

This method, in my opinion, offers the *easiest* way to lookup a person...

```js
console.log(people1[127])
// {name: "shannon", age: 43}
```

... but I don't know if it's the best. My worries are:

- I feel like objects are meant to contain information regarding one singular thing and arrays are meant for a collection of things. In this case, I guess the people could be considered a single user-base?
- Reordering items would be difficult. I'm trying to use this data in a Vuejs app which uses `v-for` to display people. In order to use this, I would probably have to have a `getter` that converts the object into an iterable list.
- Related to point above, it's difficult to iterate over this.

**METHOD 2: An array of objects where the lookup ID is stored as a property in each object**

```js
const people2 = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'bob',
        weight: 180
    },
    {
        id: 25,
        name: 'chris',
        gender: 'male'
    },
    {
        id: 127,
        name: 'shannon',
        age: 43
    },
]
```

Using this method, there are many ways I can think of that allows for data retrieval. You can see a StackOverflow discussion on these different options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property).

```js
// Using .find()
console.log(people2.find(person => person.id === 127));
// {id: 127, name: "shannon", age: 43}


// Using .forEach()
people2.forEach((person) => {
    if (person.id === 127) {
        console.log(person);
    }
});
// {id: 127, name: "shannon", age: 43}


// Using for loop
for (var i = 0; i < people2.length; i++) { 
    if (people2[i].id === 127) { 
      console.log(people2[i]);
      break;
    } 
  }
// {id: 127, name: "shannon", age: 43}


// Using .filter()
console.log(people2.filter((person) => {return person.id === 127})[0]);
// {id: 127, name: "shannon", age: 43}
```

My worries here are:

- Finding a person on a lookup ID is not as easy as the first option. I know I can make a function and use that, but I feel like that wouldn't be best performance-wise compared to method 1.
- As stated above, I am trying to use this in a Vuejs store. If I want to mutate a person, each of my mutations would have to find the person first which would call for repeated code. I could use a function, but it would have to be imported into my vuex store or above my vuex instance since I can't call a getter inside a mutation.

Comment: Both ways have their cons and pros. The first one with an object you can better imagine as a dictionary type so it suits better if you have objects with unique keys and you wish to get them quickly by a key not wasting time by iterating them.

Comment: I prefer an object for this but either one is fine.  Agree, concern #1) is an unfounded concern:  objects are suited for holding collections (like a dictionary). Concerns #2 & #3) are unfounded:  objects are iterable.  Any sorting would be done using a getter that outputs an array of just ids to iterate.  Tip:  Put the ID in each item's data too, despite also using it as the object key.  Yes, this is good and very helpful (otherwise, if you were to pass the item to a function, for example, you wouldn't know its id in the function)