# Loop to get value based on key name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the JSON response I am getting. From this JSON response, I want to get the value of "fees" based on "detailComponent" with "FULL_FEE" only. But, somehow it gets the last value of "detailComponent" with "SUB_FEE" or others which is not correct.

I am sure not how to make this for loop condition to fix my issue. Can help to guide pls?

```js
let data = {
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "result": {
        "originData": {
            "detailType": "MSG",
            "origin": [
                {
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "detailComponent": "FULL_FEE",
                            "fees": 13564.00
                        },
                        {
                            "detailComponent": "SUB_FEE",
                            "fees": 8207.60
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

var getData = data.result.originData.origin[0].details[0].detailComponent;
console.log('getData: ', getData);
```

Comment: not reproducible, seems to work fine

Comment: Sorry.. Based on "FULL_FEE", i need to extract fees value (in this ex: 13564.00)

Comment: `console.log(data.result.originData.origin[0].details.filter(v => v.detailComponent === 'FULL_FEE')[0].fees)`

Comment: ^ `.filter(...)[0]` = `.find(...)`

Comment: can do many ways.. question is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property

Comment: What do you expect if the "FULL_FEE" is present in *details* multiple times? What if there is another *origin* with "FULL_FEE"? Does this never happen and are you simply looking for the value of the first match?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the array into a dictionary by the key (detailComponent) and the number (fees).

```
// Create Array
var items = [];

// Loop Through It
data.result.originData.origin[0].details.forEach((el, index) => items[el.detailComponent] = el.fees);

// Test
console.log(items["FULL_FEE"]);
```