# how to get array of objects based on object list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects, arrayobject

I have array of object and object in which have to

1. check the arrobj `code` and obj `value` are same,
2. if above condition ok, then check the obj `idtype` and arrobj `code`

is same or obj.idtype value exists then return array list or return []

of object in javascript

```
var arrobj = [
  {id:1, code: "brown", type: "FR"},
  {id:3, code: "black", type: "SP"},
 {id:4, code: "blue", type: "FR"}
]

var obj={
  id:20, idtype: "SG", value: "blue"
}

Expected Output
// arrobj.code and obj.value matches, obj.idtype and arraobj.type not same
[]

var arrobj2 = [
  {id:1, code: "brown", type: "FR"},
  {id:3, code: "green", type: "SP"},
 {id:4, code: "blue", type: "FR"},
{id:5, code: "blue", type: "SG"}
]

var obj2={
  id:20, idtype: "SG", value: "blue"
}

Expected Output
// arrobj.code and obj.value matches, obj.idtype value exists in arraobj.type
[
{id:4, code: "blue", type: "FR"},
{id:5, code: "blue", type: "SG"}
]
```

Comment: in the second sample why do you have type: FR ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis thanks for reply, because arrobj2.code  and obj2.code matches but not type and idtype

Comment: @jeremy-denis 2nd point `then check the obj idtype and arrobj code

is same or obj.idtype value exists then return that code  matched array list

Comment: Second check - If `obj.idtype` and `arrobj.code` is same then obviously `obj.idtype` is exist. So we can chek only if `obj.idtype` is exist.

Comment: @A1exandrBelan thanks for reply, yes, i mean the obj.idtype value should check

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter a javascript object array (*code: equal and type: non equal*) you can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
const sampleCars1 = [
  {id: 1, code: "brown", type: "FR"},
  {id: 2, code: "black", type: "SP"},
  {id: 3, code: "green", type: "Y1"},
  {id: 4, code: "blue", type: "FR"}
];

const sampleCars2 = [
  {id: 1, code: "brown", type: "FR"},
  {id: 2, code: "black", type: "X1"},
  {id: 3, code: "green", type: "SP"},
  {id: 4, code: "blue", type: "FR"},
  {id: 5, code: "blue", type: "SG"},
  {id: 6, code: "blue", type: "A1"},
  {id: 7, code: "blue", type: "A2"}
];

const filterCars = (cars, desiredCode, undesiredType) => {
  return cars.filter(item => 
                        item.code === desiredCode && item.type !== undesiredType);
}

const filterSampleLists = () => {
  const filter = {id:20, type: "SG", code: "blue"};
  const filteredSample1 = filterCars(sampleCars1, filter.code, filter.type);
  const filteredSample2 = filterCars(sampleCars2, filter.code, filter.type);

  console.log(filteredSample1);
  console.log(filteredSample2);
}

filterSampleLists();
```

**Mozilla Documentation:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

**Similar Questions:**

[Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

[Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value of property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property)

**Bonus:**

- always use meaningful names
- use let/const instead of var. Check [let statement](https://ttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for more.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to fit your conditions

```js
const arrobj1 = [{id:1, code: "brown", type: "FR"},{id:3, code: "black", type: "SP"},{id:4, code: "blue", type: "FR"}];
const obj1 = { id:20, idtype: "SG", value: "blue" };

const arrobj2 = [{id:1, code: "brown", type: "FR"},{id:3, code: "green", type: "SP"},{id:4, code: "blue", type: "FR"},{id:5, code: "blue", type: "SG"}];
const obj2 = { id:20, idtype: "SG", value: "blue" };

const advFilter = (arr, obj) => {
    const filtered = arr.filter(({ code }) => code === obj.value);
    const types = filtered.map(({ type }) => type);
    return types.includes(obj.idtype) ? filtered : [];
};

console.log(advFilter(arrobj1, obj1));
console.log(advFilter(arrobj2, obj2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```