# Making a search in json file by query

Tags: javascript, json, search

i want to make a search in a json file by query
Example:
My json file:

```
[{
"Id":1,
"name":"test"
},
{
"Id":2,
"name":"test"
}]
```

### And if i search {"name":"test"} i get the full objects whos name is test

ADD: I misspoke its the user who enter the query how can i get the key and the value from the query {key:value} and the user can entre multiple keys and values (like the search in atlas mongodb)
UP!!

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your question you are using JSON inside of an array.
So you can simply filter the array to find JSON which contains name="test"

Follow the below step:

```
let userArray = [{"Id":1,"name":"test"},{"Id":2,"name":"test"}]

const filteredUser = userArray.filter((user) => user.name === "test")
```

Comment: I misspoke its the user who enter the query how can i get the key and the value from the query {key:value} and the user can entre multiple keys and values (like the search in atlas mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple:

```js
var myjson ='[{"Id":1,"name":"test"},{"Id":2,"name":"test"},{"Id":3,"name":"nottest"}]';
var slag = JSON.parse(myjson).filter(doc => doc.name === 'test');
console.log(slag);
```