# Filter Array of objects (API response) based on flag in database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net

I am receiving a large array of objects using the below method:

```
const GetList = async () => {
  const [data, error] = await GetList();
  console.log(response);
```

This gives me back an array of 1000 elements, there is an isActive flag on every element and I need to filter out the elements that are not active.

I am not able to use

```
var resultFiltered = response.filter(obj =>{
  return obj.isActive === 'true'
});
```

As it gives me an error message
[image]

The entire array is stored in the data variable, how can I filter out all elements that are not active?

Comment: Use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?  Though if you don't need this data client-side, it would make a lot more sense to filter it server-side.

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property

Comment: I edited the question, it's an array of objects, and every object has a property, isActive, that's the property I need to filter the array of objects on, so I need an entire array of objects that are active, and all not active filtered out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using response variable, since the value is fetched variable data, try filtering as shown below

```
  const GetList = async () => {
    const data = await GetList();
    const resultFiltered = data.filter(obj => Boolean(obj.isActive) === true);
    console.log(resultFiltered);
  }
```

Comment: How do I filter on all objects in the array? I can access the first object like so: console.log(response.data.data[0]); I need to filter all the objects that have response.data.data.isActive === true. I tried const resultFiltered = response.filter(obj => Boolean(obj.data.data.isAddon) === true); but I get Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.filter is not a function

Comment: try response.data.data.filter(obj => Boolean(obj.isActive) === true)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, the response variable is not an array-type variable please check that out. If it's an object then convert it into an array and then apply the filter function.

`const resultFiltered = Object.values(response).filter(obj => obj.isActive === true);`

Answer (score 0):

Test the bellow code:

> response.data.filter()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).