# How to get an object from an array with the element id is same

Tags: javascript, filter

I have a question, how to get one object from an object array?

The object array looks like this:

```js
const allData = [{
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    service: {
      id: "123",
      name: "name1"
    }
  },
  {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    service: {
      id: "222",
      name: "name2"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to get the object with `service.id` is 222.

What should the code look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value of property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property)

Comment: This is a simple problem and can be done through some research/effort.

Answer (score 1):

Works with [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

> returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

```js
const allData = [{
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    service: {
      id: "123",
      name: "name1"
    }
  },
  {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    service: {
      id: "222",
      name: "name2"
    }
  }
]

let obj = allData.find(x => x.service.id == "222");

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [filter Array prototype method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  especially if you could have more than one object having the `"222"` value for the `service.id` property in the array.

> The filter() method creates a shallow copy of a portion of a given array, filtered down to just the elements from the given array that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
const result = allData.filter(obj => obj.service.id === "222");

console.log(result);
```