# How can I get an element of one object where the object has the element id="..."

Tags: javascript

I receive answer from a form. I receive an array with objects where each object correspond to the answer of one question:

[image]

I want to access the answer.

First I was thinking to ask to use `answers[i].t` (for example), but the problem is that the number of the question depends of the answers submitted so I can't use index of the array. So I had the idea to access to the answer by using the id of the question.

For example: `object.t` where `object.q === "64c3980b7e457155fed418db"`.

How can I do that in JavaScript?

Comment: The equivalent of a 'where' clause when searching through an array of objects would be either [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13964186/519413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method:

```js
answers.find(item => item.q  === "64c3980b7e457155fed418db");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getId = answers?.findIndex(object.q === "64c3980b7e457155fed418db");
```

Comment: Do not add code only answer. Explain what it do

Comment: If you're going to use the `findIndex` route, you should probably also show the step where you are actually getting the object from the array.